# How to plot pendulum motion for Elastic Pendulum with Spring in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I have a code that creates the correct xy plot for elastic pendulum with spring.  I would like to show an animation of the elastic spring pendulum on an xy plot as the system marches forward in time.  How can this be done?

Here is my simulation code:

```
clc
clear all;

%Define parameters

global M K L g;
M = 1;
K = 25.6;
L = 1;
g = 9.8;


% define initial values for theta, thetad, del, deld
theta_0 = 0;
thetad_0 = .5;
del_0 = 1;
deld_0 = 0;
initialValues = [theta_0, thetad_0, del_0, deld_0];

% Set a timespan
t_initial = 0;
t_final = 36;
dt = .1;
N = (t_final - t_initial)/dt;
timeSpan = linspace(t_final, t_initial, N);

% Run ode45 to get z (theta, thetad, del, deld)
[t, z] = ode45(@OdeFunHndlSpngPdlmSym, timeSpan, initialValues);

% initialize empty column vectors for theta, thetad, del, deld
M_loop = zeros(N, 1);
L_loop = zeros(N, 1);
theta = zeros(N, 1);
thetad = zeros(N, 1);
del = zeros(N, 1);
deld = zeros(N, 1);
T = zeros(N, 1);
x = zeros(N, 1);
y = zeros(N, 1);

% Assign values for variables (theta, thetad, del, deld)
for i = 1:N
    M_loop(i) = M;
    L_loop(i) = L;
    theta(i) = z(i, 1);
    thetad(i) = z(i, 2);
    del(i) = z(i, 3);
    deld(i) = z(i, 4);
    T(i) = (M*(thetad(i)^2*(L + del(i))^2 + deld(i)^2))/2;
    V(i) = (K*del(i)^2)/2 + M*g*(L - cos(theta(i))*(L + del(i)));
    E(i) = T(i) + V(i);
    x(i) = (L + del(i))*sin(theta(i));
    y(i) = -(L + del(i))*cos(theta(i));
end

figure(1)
plot(x, y,'r');
title('XY Plot');
xlabel('x position');
ylabel('y position');
```

Here is my function code:

```
function dz = OdeFunHndlSpngPdlmSym(~, z)
% Define Global Parameters
global M K L g


% Take output from SymDevFElSpringPdlm.m file for fy1 and fy2 and
% substitute into z2 and z4 respectively
%fy1=thetadd=z(2)= -(M*g*sin(z1)*(L + z3) + M*z2*z4*(2*L + 2*z3))/(M*(L + z3)^2)
%fy2=deldd=z(4)=((M*(2*L + 2*z3)*z2^2)/2 - K*z3 + M*g*cos(z1))/M

% return column vector [thetad; thetadd; deld; deldd]
dz = [z(2);
    -(M*g*sin(z(1))*(L + z(3)) + M*z(2)*z(4)*(2*L + 2*z(3)))/(M*(L + z(3))^2);
    z(4);
    ((M*(2*L + 2*z(3))*z(2)^2)/2 - K*z(3) + M*g*cos(z(1)))/M];
```

Comment: Thanks I ran the added code but the graph keeps zooming into the point at the end of vector.  I would like to keep the extents of xy graph still but have the pendulum in order to visualize pendulum motion.

Answer (score 0):

You can "simulate" animation in a plot with a continous updating FOR loop and assignig graphic object to variables.

Something like (I assume only to use x,y as arrays function of time array t)

```
%In order to block the axis and preventing continuous zoom, choose proper axes limit
x_lim = 100; %these values depends on you, these are examples 
y_lim = 100;
axis equal
axis([-x_lim x_lim -y_lim y_lim]); %now x and y axes are fixed from -100 to 100
ax = gca;


for i=1:length(t)
 if i > 1
  delete(P);
  delete(L);
 end

 P = plot(x(i),y(i)); %draw the point
 hold on
 L = quiver(0,0,x(i),y(i)); %draw a vector from 0,0 to the point
 hold on
 %other drawings
 drawnow
 pause(0.1) %pause in seconds needed to simulate animaton. 
end
```

"Hold on" instruction after every plot instruction. 
This is only a basic animation, of course.

Comment: Thanks I ran the added code but the graph keeps zooming into the point at the end of vector. I would like to keep the extents of xy graph still but have the pendulum in order to visualize pendulum motion.

Comment: @PatStarks I updated the answers. If it does not work again (graph not still) try not to use "drawnow" and oly use "hold on" after every line of code related to a plot instruction (at least 1 instruction for every component of your pendulum).